# Can I display something while a macro is running?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that takes roughly five seconds to execute and I'm using the code `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` so it looks like Word has locked up when it's running.

I use a message box at the end to tell them it's complete, but I'd like to display an image during its execution that tells the user the macro is running (primarily so they don't get worried, but also because it's nicer to look at).

There might be an easier way to go about this, but I decided to create an image, create a very basic user form, and simply set my image as its background.  Then, I have that user form pop up as soon as the code starts to run.

The problem I'm having is that unless I close it, the rest of the code won't execute.  It just hangs until I do something.  Is there a way I can get the user form to be displayed without stopping the rest of the process?  If not, is there another approach I can take to display an image while the macro is running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can show the userform as non-modal:

```
Userform1.Show False
'do more stuff (doesn't wait for form to close)
Userform1.Hide
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim.  That works almost perfectly.  The only problem is that while the user form loads (and closes) properly... and the code executes behind the user form, the content of the user form (the picture) never displays.  It's like there's too much action happening for it to show.

Other than trying a picture with a smaller file size, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Try adding a `DoEvents` after showing the form.  Also make sure you're not suppressing screenupdating when the form is first displayed.

Comment: This is so odd.  Adding `DoEvents` worked better, but instead of leaving it displayed while the code runs, it only displays it for less than a second and then it disappears.  I'm not suppressing the screen updating until after the `userform.Show` and `DoEvents` lines.

Comment: "It" is the userform, or the picture?

Comment: Tried using an image control instead of setting the form background?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.  When I said "it  disappears," I meant the entire user form. The picture showed properly for the short time the form was on the screen. Originally, I was setting a picture as the background of the user form.  When that didn't work, I tried a smaller picture and then I tried using an image control.  Every approach I tried had the same result. I just tried something different and I finally got it to work as intended.  The macro was opening a document towards the beginning.  I moved the `Userform1.Show False` line after that and now it displays until the end of the macro.

Answer (score 0):

I too have found that if you .show a userform at the beginning of the process, images contained within userform take a while to display and the result is less than smooth.

I have solved it by inserting a 1 second "wait" immediately after the userform.show instruction. In that split second, the image loads and displays successfully and the result is seamless.

Here the code. I have 2 macros: 1 to display and 1 to hide. I call the first macro at the beginning of the process just before freezing the screen and the second at the end of the process just before unfreezing the screen

Userform name is "myuserform"

```
Sub message_show()
userform.Show False
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub message_hide()
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
userform.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing this. Unfortunately, I haven't done any VBA coding in years, so I don't really have any way of trying this out now.  I'm not sure if I even still have the code for the project I had been working on, but hopefully someone else will find this useful. Cheers!